# Gather a repeating 2-group pattern

Tags: regex, pcre

I am looking for a Regex that would return from the following

> **The law** of Huxley **S**omething interesting. Some other interesting thing.
> **The law** of Dallas **T**his thing is boring.
> **The law** of void **S**ome stuff.

as a 2-line text where 2 groups have been identified :

1. first group that starts with "The law" and finishes at the first capital letter ;
2. second group that starts afterwards and ends when the next fisrt group "The law"
   pattern is encountered.

I aim to rephrase it by separating the title from core text using capturing groups like this :

```
The law of Huxley 
Something interesting. Some other interesting thing. 

The law of Dallas 
This thing is boring.

The law of void
Some stuff.
```

I have tried with

```
((The law [\w\s]+)([A-Z].+))+
```

to no avail

Comment: What programming language or regex flavor are you using?

Comment: What are your exact requirements? Match and capture all from `The law`, next word, then till the next uppercase letter that begins the next capture that goes up to the next `The law` or end of string? `(The law\s+\w+\s\P{Lu}*)(\p{Lu}.*?)(?=The law|$)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/oQsRds/2/))?

Comment: Or after the first capitalized word? https://regex101.com/r/1XfTpG/1

Comment: You did well @WiktorStribiżew ; I was actually looking for separating some titles mixed with core text using the capturing groups. I missed the positive lookahead part for it to work. Thank you for your time. Do not hesitate to post a reply so that I can mark it as an good answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(The law\s+\w+\s\P{Lu}*)(\p{Lu}.*?)(?=The law|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oQsRds/2/).

*Details*:

- `(The law\s+\w+\s\P{Lu}*)` - Group 1: `The law` text, then one or more whitespace, one or more word chars, a whitespace, and then any zero or more chars other than uppercase letters
- `(\p{Lu}.*?)` - Group 2: an uppercase letter, and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, up to the first occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns
- `(?=The law|$)` - a positive lookahead that requires either `The law` or end of string immediately to the right of the current location.